# OSX Services - character substitution + for _

Tags: macos, automator, osx-elcapitan, osx-services

I've created a service to use primarily in a browser for searching IMDB, so instead of copying and pasting the film's name I just select the text and run the service I created which will automatically search IMDB for the selected text. This works perfect.

[image]

I was hoping to do the same for Wikipedia and so i've been trying to modify the same service but have come across a problem. The search query places a "+" between each word.

[image]

This doesn't work for Wikipedia. They place underscores between their words.

[image]

I wondered how I can substitute the + for _?
This is what I currently have

```
open "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"
```

Kinds regards and Merry Christmas :)

Comment: I think you are better off asking here: https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute every space for underscore with the **gsub()** command before the **escape** command.

```
open "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp.gsub(" ", "_")')"
```